# regex behaves differently in c# than on regexr.com

Tags: c#, regex

I looked around for a regex that will extract a url from a string and found this one.

```
\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))
```

The problem is when I test it on the following string at regexr.com it matches properly, but not when I use it in c#.

**Test String:**

```
  "<a style=\"color: blue;\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://www.fedex.com/Tracking?action=track&tracknumbers=187880016501597\">Track FedEx Ground 187880016501597</a>"
```

**Regexr Match:**

```
  "http://www.fedex.com/Tracking?action=track&tracknumbers=187880016501597"
```

**C# Match:**

```
  "http://www.fedex.com/Tracking?action=track&tracknumbers=187880016501597">"
```

I can't figure out why the c# is adding the "> at the end of the matching string. I think it may have something to do with the escape character that comes before it in the original test string. I'm looking to get the same result that regexr.com gets. Let me know if anyone has any ideas, thanks.

Comment: What are all the backslashes in the HTML for?

Comment: And (following on what @Asad wrote) are you properly escaping them in C#, either by using `@""` or extra backslashes?

Comment: oh my yea screwed the pooch on this question I edited it now. The test string is actually an entire html link.

Comment: @mgmedick I think something is still broken. The matches include an `href=` bit which is no longer shown in the test string.

Comment: RegexBuddy tool (not free) can help debug regexes in various implementations (including .net, php, and others), and show exactly how engine matches and backtraces.  Not exactly the answer you're looking for, but hope it helps.

Comment: sorry me being a dummy (Friday fever), didn't mark the text as code. so it was creating links

Comment: The reason there is a backslash is because I'm trying to extract the url from an html link

Comment: What is `[^[:punct:]\s]` meant to be/mean? Any character except a `[`, a `:`, a `p`, a `u`, a `n`, a `c`, or a `t`? Then followed why any whitespace and then a `]`? Look suspicious to me!

Comment: I honestly have no idea, but after further investigation it looks like it does have something to do with the escape character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Lasse (in the comments). has pointed you in the right direction for the reason that you're getting the additional character match.

.NET Regexes don't support [POSIX character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class) so `[:punct:]` won't be matching punctuation and symbols `[!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@ [\\\]^_{|}~]` (which the original regex is relying on). You'll either have to substitute in the desired punctuation symbols (which would look quite cumbersome), or find an alternative regex.

Additional details on supported/unsupported behaviour can be found here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a play with the Regex you listed and got it to work with a minor tweak to the bit that matches parts of the url:

From:

```
[^\s()<>]
```

Changed to:

```
[.])[^\s()<>\"\\]
```

This excludes the characters at the end which you didn't want. So the final Regex is:

```
\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>\"\\]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([[^\w]\s]|)))
```

As to what the `:punct:` bit is all about, I have no idea! Maybe it is some character set your regex tool for punctuation. Not sure. Anyway, I tweaked it as shown above and for your test case at least, it works. However, that part of the Regex may need a bit of attention given some more sample data.